# Why aren't gTLD domains sold in a unified price?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, international, pricing, country-codes

As far as I understand, the Israeli Internet association (*ISOC-IL*),
always sold domains with Israeli `ccTLDs` (`.*.il`),
whether directly or indirectly (through its representatives or through the representatives of domain-registrar companies supervised by it),
**by unified price** policy (I believe around 80 NIS per year),
with the virtue of *first come, first served* policy (**FCFS** | in Hebrew: *כל הקודם זוכה*).

So far I worked only with this authoritative body *ISOC-IL*, to register domains, but I feel I no longer want to keep work with it in general from various reasons.

When I visit well known international domain registrars such as *godaddy* and *namecheap*, I get entirely different prices for different domains;
That is to say, there seems to me to be no unity in pricing as opposed to the policies virtued by *ISOC-IL*.

**Why aren't gTLD domains sold in a unified price?**
<sub>or this is a false premise and they do, somewhere, or at least should be?</sub>

### Update

I seem to have had a mistake → in 2016 a "quiet" reform was made to stop *ISOC-IL*s direct domain registration as well as *supervision of domain prices*; since then, there was no maximal price and now every company can price a domain per algorithm (as common with international companies) so it could cost way more than 80 NIS for one year or 180 NIS for two years;
Yet, I am impressed most companies supervised by *ISOC-IL* have since kept pretty much the same prices to not upset regular customers.

Answer (score 6):

> Why aren't gTLD domains sold in a unified price?

Why should they? We live  in a world where economy is bound by offers and demands, isn't it? So sellers are free to set their prices, and buyers are free to pay that price or not.

And your question could be for all TLDs, not just gTLDs.

Domains were free, back in the days, before the world wide web become famous and widespread and hence the whole Internet with it.

IANA delegates TLDs to relevant organizations: either countries for ccTLDs, or any organization having passed the ICANN programs to get a gTLD.

Each of these organizations is free to set the pricing policy it wants. In some ccTLDs the price is not the same depending on who is the registrant. In gTLDs, previous ICANN rules constrained the registries in price changes; but newer ones have lifted all of this, and you can find the latest case with the .ORG controversy.

Each TLD is run by its own organization with its own form (non profit or for profit), rules, constraints, objectives, etc. Of course there is some concentration, so some organizations now run multiple TLDs but even so they may consider it as separate business units that each needs to be profitable, irrespective to what other TLDs do.

In ccTLDs, some organizations are under contract with the respective government and then has such constraints as having to pay the government yearly some amount of money, or as being forced to run the business on a cost basis, without profit and hence adjusting prices each year (normally only going down, as more domains should mean a lower cost per domain as the total costs vary little with the total number of domains in the TLD)

Also in most TLDs, but not all; the registry does not sell directly to end customers, but only to registrars. That price is fixed, and can just vary sometimes if the registry does some promotions that can impact some registrars and not others. Then registrars are free to put whatever margin they want on top of it, based on their business model. Some, like a famous CDN recently, claimed they want to offer all TLDs at cost, without margin for them; of course it just means they will earn money through other services and packages bound to the domain.

It seems to me you didn't recall that even in a given single TLD, not all domain names may have the same cost; Either depending on when they are registered (during EAP at the start of a TLD life, domains cost more), or because of their content (many gTLDs have premiums domain names, again because of offer and demand situation, some names are considered by registry as having more value and hence cost more; and those prices can change during time, or new names becoming premium or leaving premium state, etc.)

Comment: Very good answer.